# Why's my vector element all garbage?

Tags: c++, stdvector, garbage

I have a `GameLobby` class that keeps a list of the currently active games. I want to fetch the active games from a `GameLobby` (singleton) object, and display these to the user.

(Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to C++, so the following code isn't exactly stellar. Neither is it the complete code, but I feel confident that all the relevant instructions have been included.)

First some definitions

```
class GamesMenu : public MyGameLayer
{
private:
    std::vector<Game*>* _activeGames;
    void displayGamesList();
    void refreshGamesList();
};
```

and

```
class MyGameLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{
private:
    GameLobby* _gameLobby;
public:
    GameLobby* getGameLobby();
};
```

and

```
GameLobby* MyGameLayer::getGameLobby()
{
    return _gameLobby;
}
```

Now to the problem at hand. I want to execute `GamesMenu::refreshGamesList()` which looks like this:

```
void GamesMenu::refreshGamesList()
{
    GameLobby* gameLobby = getGameLobby();
    if (gameLobby) {
        _activeGames = gameLobby->getActiveGames();
        Game* game = _activeGames->at(0); // For debug purposes only - this game is NOT garbage
    }
    displayGamesList();
}
```

where

```
std::vector<Game*>* GameLobby::getActiveGames()
{
    if (_loggedInPlayer) {
        refreshActiveGames(_loggedInPlayer->GetPlayerToken());
    } else {
        refreshActiveGames("");
    }
    return &_activeGames;
};
```

and `std::vector<Game*> _activeGames` is a private member of `GameLobby`.

However, when execution hits `displayGamesList()`, things get pretty bad

```
void GamesMenu::displayGamesList()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _activeGames->size(); i++) {
        Game* game = _activeGames->at(i); // The contents of game is garbage. Why?
        std::string opponentName = game->GetOpponentName(); // This I don't even want to talk about 
    };
    /* Supressed drawing stuff */
}
```

When I inspect `game` in `GamesMenu::refreshGamesList`, the contents of `game` seems fine. When I inspect `game` in `GamesMenu::displayGamesList`, the contents is all garbage. It is as if the elements of the vector points to the wrong data or something.

Can anyone please help me untangle myself out of this mess? Thanks! :)

Comment: The fact that you are using pointers makes me a little uncomfortable. It makes me wonder where vector is being allocated and it complicates the memory management.

Comment: [A good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will talk about `std::vector`s and how to use them properly, so I highly recommend that you pick such a book up. While you're at it, [stop using pointers so much](http://klmr.me/slides/modern%2Dcpp.pdf). Kudos to you for using the standard containers though.

Comment: Yeah, that surely adds a level of abstraction. The reason I do this, is that I tried to copy the vector. But this didn't work for me at all. I didn't get any sensible result from my attempt at 'std::vector<Game*> GameLobby::getActiveGames()'. I'm not sure why, but suspecting it might be related to elements not being copied correctly(?). Basically what I wonder is: why can I see the contents of the vector in one method and not in the next? Nothing significant happened between the two calls ...

Comment: If you store things in a vector, returning the address of that vector is the wrong thing to do. Return a const reference to the vector, assuming you don't intent to modify it.

Comment: Your code snippets doesn't show the declaration or initialization of `_activeGames`. I suspect what happens is that your pointer goes stale (points to data that is no longer available) in some way.

Comment: @MatsPetersson that definitely seems like a sound advice - I'm not going to modify the vector. Regarding the snippets, I tried to keep the post as small as possible, but I think I'll want to update it later today.

Comment: Shouldn't the return value of `getActiveGames()` be only `_activeGames` instead of `&_activeGames` ?

Comment: @UchiaItachi I think `GameLobby` is the home of the actual *instance* (not just a pointer to) the active games vector. Consequently, returning its address makes sense. What I don't understand is, if `GameMenu` is opened from a `GameLobby`, why doesn't the menu just always use the lobby's `getActiveGames()` member and keep *no* `_activeGames` pointer in its instance whatsoever.

Comment: @WhozCraig yup, that's why. Regarding keeping a pointer to '_activeGames' in 'GameLobby': don't really need to, no. I'm going to try access it directly.

Comment: @conciliator I meant get rid of the pointer in GameMenu (since it has a pointer to the lobby, and thus access to its `getActiveGames()` exposure.)

Comment: @WhozCraig wow man - that did it! (Unfortunately, I'm still in dark as to why the pointer '_activeGames' didn't do what I thought it should've done.)

Comment: @WhozCraig yup, got that. :) Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @conciliator Without seeing the constructor for GamesMenu and how that variable is initialized and maintained I would have difficulty speculating *exactly* why it works, but it was likely in that area. Glad its working.

Comment: check the following method  `   if (_loggedInPlayer) {
        refreshActiveGames(_loggedInPlayer->GetPlayerToken());
    } else {
        refreshActiveGames("");`  check the value of _loggedInPlayer and then check refreshActiveGames check to see if loggedInPlayer is being set also check ` if (gameLobby) ` as I think that gameLobby is probably not being set and you are returning a reference to an uninitialized vector. You need to share your code for populating the vector and vet that out to make sure it is being called

Comment: Other good example of ***Java++***